# Creating image in php only works when nothing else happens on page

Tags: php

I'm using this piece of php code to create and rotate an image. And it works perfectly when i just call the img.php it lying in.

But if i try to include the img.php in anything else, or just include the snippet in another page (on same server) it just shows me a lot of questionmarks instead of an image.

My feeling is that the problem is related to the headers sent, but honestly i have no idea.

Any suggestions how to make this useful so it can be included in another page and still work?

```
<?php 
   header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
   // option one  
  // create a 250*77 image 
  $im = imagecreate(250, 77); 
  // option two  
  // creating a image from jpeg  
  $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg("images/test.jpg")  
  or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream"); 

  // white background and black text 
  $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255); 
  $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); 

 //create the text
  $skrivetekst = date('d.m.Y');
    $skrivetekst2 = date('H:i:s');

 // write the string at the top left 
  imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $skrivetekst, $textcolor); 
  imagestring($im, 5, 0, 20, $skrivetekst2, $textcolor); 


 ///Rotate the image 
$rotate = imagerotate($im, 90, 0);
  // output the image 


// Output
imagejpeg($rotate);


  ImageDestroy ($rotate); 
?>
```

Regards Troels

Comment: What do you mean by "a lot of question marks"? Does the image fail to load? What does Firebug's net tab say about whether it gets loaded?

Comment: Here you can see the questionmarks: http://tm-design.dk/kontrabande/

Comment: or probl better, a screendumb: http://tm-design.dk/kontrabande/problem.png

Comment: that's the binary of your outputted image, it will show asif you opened a jpeg image in a text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, your script should response to the browser with an output of certain type, usual output is `text/html`, that contains html content. To output an image, you send the `Content-type: image/jpeg` header, followed by image binary content (via `imagejpeg($rotate);`).

The errors showing in your case are probably due to you are trying to send the header after echoing html/text content. Once output is sent, you can't send more headers.

To output php-generated images within php-generated html, you need to split that in two pages, one to output the image, and another to output html, the html output will reference your image via the regular `<img>` tag, as @GSto mentioned.

---

**EDIT:**

page.php:

```
<html>
 <head><title>HI!</title></head>
 <body><?php
  //here goes your html building logic
  /*If you are not using and PHP, make this page page.html*/
  ?>
  See my php-generated image: <br />
  <img src="img.php" />
  </body>
</html>
```

img.php:

```
<?php 
   header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
   // option one  
  // create a 250*77 image 
  $im = imagecreate(250, 77); 
  //rest of your image-generating code..
```

You will access the first page in your browser, that will see the `<img>` tag, request the next file and get the content to show as that tag.

Comment: But does that mean that the creation of the image has to be the first thing happening on the first page loaded?

Comment: can you give me an example of splitting the plage in 2, because i don't really get how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

probably because you are using different header types on a page, and it's not using the image header. If you want to put it on a page, i would put it in an image tag and call it that way:

```
<img src='img.php'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call [`imagejpeg()`](http://php.net/imagejpeg) on the same page as your HTML content.

Browsers expect images to received in a seperate request then your HTML content. If you want to embed a PHP generated image inside your page, you must have two different PHP scripts.

For example, you can have a file called `my_page.php` which generates the wanted HTML markup:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Look at this nice dynamic image! Generated on <?php echo date(); ?>.</p>
    <img src="my_image.php" />
  </body>
</html>
```

and a file called `my_image.php` which generates the wanted image:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$date = date();
$x = imagefontwidth(5) * strlen($date);
$y = imagefontheight(5);

$img = imagecreate($x, $y);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);
imagestring($img, 5, 0, 0, $date, $textcolor);

imagejpeg($img);
```

As you can see, the image is displayed by including an `<img>` tag which points to `my_image.php`. You cannot run [`imagejpeg()`](http://php.net/imagejpeg) on the same page as your HTML content (unless using the `$filename` parameter, [see documentation](http://php.net/imagejpeg)). If you have variables to pass to `my_image.php`, you may use GET parameters to do so.