# image create by php function not called on multiple php files

Tags: php

This is drawing.php file having class GeoDrawing and method image which creates the image. I now create the object of this class and call the function and image return successfully.

When I include this file 'drawing.php' to another php file - let say server.php - then this function does not return image.

Please help me out. What is going wrong with this code?

```
class GeoDrawing
{        
    public  $canvas;

     function Image()
     {        
        $this->canvas = imagecreate(2600, 1200) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
        imagecolorallocate($this->canvas, 225, 225, 225);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');  
        imagejpeg($home->canvas);       
     }
}

$home = new GeoDrawing();
$home->image();
```

Comment: In addition to what @wavemode said... I would gladly edit your post to make it more comprehensible but it is so bad I'm lost at what you are trying to say. Please revise this.

Comment: ok am new here if you got my point then help me plz..

Comment: It could be a lot of things. Does your server.php prints any additional output?

Comment: You've got `display_errors` on, right? .. right?

Comment: not error just small dummy pic show on top left corner of the browser

Comment: no my server.php just call function image()

Comment: @Ben errors are not showing because of the mime type nit being text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, your function does not "return" anything. It prints out the image. As such it does not work if anything was printed out before the function call. That us because you are setting a header. And imagejpeg prints out the image, so if you have any output after that, it gets added to your image data and corrupts it. I would suggest reviewing your server.php to ensure no printout bevore function call. And perhaps use an exit() inside your function to ensure no orintout afterwards. But remember, that this stops execution so the function would never return.

**Edit:**

Your program is throwing errors! Please comment the header() to view them. Because else your browser expects a valid image and instead gets php error messages.

your codeproblem is a scope typo:

```
imagejpeg($home->canvas);
```

to

```
imagejpeg($this->canvas);
```

To help you understand your problem, you can look [at others having similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670301/creating-image-in-php-only-works-when-nothing-else-happens-on-page?rq=1), i think that gives a good example.

Comment: <?php
include "Drawing.php";
$home = new GeoDrawing(); 
$home->image(); 
?>

Comment: Is there any space character before the <?php   ?

Comment: Can you view the source code of your site? Because of your new mime type errors are not displayed as text

Comment: i have no site just using local Linux server plz give me your gmail id the i will send you the source code

Comment: Please use Strg + U and tell me the text your browser displays

Comment: I will try your code later when I am on my station and will update this answer then.

Comment: @GhulamMujtaba well, i edited my answer, you simply got a typo in your code but the errors are not displayed because you send an image and no text.